# How can i replace some part in string except some word using regular expression in android

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I have 100 such files with string containing Vol - {some digit}. I want to replace all word except this Vol - {0-9}.

**Problem**: Kirtan _ Vol - 4 _ android - 1 _ bhai sahib.mp3

**Needed Result**: Vol - 4.mp3

Comment: Hello, can you add an example of the closest you got to the correct answer, or narrow down your question to part of a regex which isn't doing what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cFTMg/1), `.*(Vol - [0-9]).*` where `.*` means any character any number of times and `(Vol - [0-9])` is the [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)(1) referred by `$1` in the code. The pattern, `[0-9]` means one digit in the range, 0-9.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Kirtan _ Vol - 4 _ android - 1 _ bhai sahib.mp3";

        str = str.replaceAll(".*(Vol - [0-9]).*", "$1");

        System.err.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Vol - 4
```

If the number of digits can be more than one, replace `[0-9]` with `[0-9]+` or `\d+`.